# Coloring PieChart elements uniformly for various charts

Tags: color, visualization, charts

I have in total 16 datasets and want to make `PieChart`s such that the colors are appropriate for the respective item. I tried with `ColorFunction` but without result

Here a MWE to illustrate the problem with two datasets, pairs (item name, value):

```
data1 = {{"Label 1", 2}, {"Label 2", 4}, {"Label 3", 4}};
data2 = {{"Label 1", 2}, {"Label 2", 4}, {"Label 4", 4}};
```

so

```
allLabels = {"Label 1", "Label 2", "Label 3", "Label 4"};

colors = Hue /@ (Range[4]/4);
```

So we get the desired colorings:

[image]

and the `colorChooser`:

```
colorChooser[label_String] := 
 Select[labelColors, First[#] == label &][[1, 2]]
```

Then:

```
PieChart[data1[[All, 2]], ChartLegends -> data1[[All, 1]],
 ColorFunction -> (colorChooser[#,1] &); (*Choose color for the item*)
 ChartElementFunction -> "PlateauSector",
 ChartLabels -> relativeData[[All, 2]]
 ]
```

delivers:

[image]

and

```
PieChart[data2[[All, 2]], ChartLegends -> data2[[All, 1]],
 ColorFunction -> (colorChooser[#,1] &); (*Choose color for the item*)   
 ChartElementFunction -> "PlateauSector",
 ChartLabels -> data2[[All, 2]]
 ]
```

[image]

The desired output would be that the items are colored according to the colortable, so "item 4" should be in red. How can I set up the `ChartLegends` and the `colorChooser` appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
coloring = Thread[allLabels -> colors];
PieChart[#[[All, 2]], ChartStyle -> #[[All, 1]] /. coloring, 
    ChartLabels -> #[[All, 1]], ChartLegends -> #[[All, 1]], 
    ChartElementFunction -> "PlateauSector", ImageSize -> 300] & /@ {data1, data2} // Row
```

[image]

Alternatively, wrap each data point with `Style` and `Labeled`:

```
{styledD1, styledD2} = Style[Labeled[#2, #], # /. coloring] & @@@ # & /@ {data1, data2};
PieChart[#, ChartLegends -> SwatchLegend[#[[All, 2]], #[[All, 1, 2]]],
  ChartElementFunction -> "PlateauSector", ImageSize -> 300] & /@ {styledD1, styledD2} // 
  Row
```

> same picture

Comment: Thank you for this fast solution - and it is so "easy" (if you know it...)

Comment: @mgamer, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.